# RoR Beginner - cannot load such file -- mysq12/2.0...WIN8, Ruby2.0,Rails3.2.13

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, file

I just started using Rails. I've been reading up for the past few hours on how to get this all set up and it's killing me that I can't figure it out. I'm running Windows 8, I installed Ruby 2.0, Rails 3.2.13, MySql2, DevKit, Connector C, everything!

So I go to create a new project: rails new Blog -d mysql

It works, it creates a new folder called Blog. I "cd blog" to get to that directory. Then I type "rake db:create" to make a new database, and an error comes up:

`cannot load such file -- mysql2/2.0/mysql2
  C:/Users/Brice/Desktop/Ruby/test rails/Blog2/config/application.rb:7:in '<top <required>>'
  C:/Users/Brice/Desktop/Ruby/test rails/Blog2/Rakefile:5:in '<top <required>>'
  <See full trace by running task with --trace>`

I don't understand what's wrong! I read that it might be my mysql2 is the problem. I reinstalled/installed that several times. Dragged the libmysql.dll file into Ruby2.0/bin folder.

I do notice that when I use `gem install mysql2` I get this:

`unable to convert "\x90" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for lib/mysql2/1.8/mysq12.so, skipping
  unable to convert "\x90" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for lib/mysql2/1.9/mysq12.so, skipping`

could that be the issue?

Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 2):

It is difficult to investigate complicated installs like this one from remote. If you are just starting, I would encourage you to use a "pre bundled" package with everything you need inside like the famous [RailsInstaller](http://railsinstaller.org/). It will get you a fully operational environment with :

- Ruby 1.9.3-p392
- Rails 3.2
- Bundler
- Git
- Sqlite
- TinyTDS
- SQL Server Support
- DevKit

You'll have plenty of opportunities later to customize your environment.

Note also that in my own and limited experience, Windows is not exactly the best environment to develop using Rails.